# Is it possible to copy the text from a protected message sent by a Telegram bot?

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I am using the `sendMessage()` function with `protected_content: true` because I don't want Telegram users to forward my bot's message to the others.

Originally the text below was copyable, but after I set `protected_content=true`, users couldn't copy the text.

```
<code>Hello, How are you?</code>
```

Is there any way to copy the above text though it is `protected_content`?

Or is there any other way to disable forwarding of telegram bot message?

Answer (score 2):

No, when passing [`protect_content`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage), every functionality that could potential 'leak' the message will be disabled.

---

Since there isn't much documentation about this, here a (probably incomplete) list of disabled functionalities:

- Forward button
- Copy text
- Screenshot when message is in view